# Match string in XText regardless of upper/lower case

Tags: java, eclipse, pattern-matching, dsl, xtext

I want to create a rule in XText that matches to a string, but does not care in what case the string is. For example, I want it to match against both "DUCK", "DucK" and "duck". Is there a more simple way of doing it than covering all cases, like:

```
Rule:
     'Duck'|'DucK'|'DuCK'|... and so on
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a flag that you can configure in the mwe2 workflow. Replace the `XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment` by the `org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.ex.rt.AntlrGeneratorFragment` and pass `options = { ignoreCase = true }`. Same for the `XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment` and the `org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.ex.ca.ContentAssistParserGeneratorFragment`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Is there any way of doing it for only a specific rule instead of doing it for everything?

Comment: Also, is it possible to create terminals that can match strings to both upper and lower case in a similar fashion?

Comment: No, there is no such option for the lexing. You may want to use case insensitive linking, though. Simply pass `ignoreCase = true` in your workflow to the scoping fragment, too.

Comment: can anyone tell me how add this code to mwe2 workflow in sample example as i am new to Xtext please help me

Answer (score 0):

FYI.

```
    language = StandardLanguage {
        ...
        parserGenerator = {
            options = {
                ignoreCase = true //Case Insensitive Keywords
            }
        }
        scopeProvider = {
            ignoreCase = true //Case Insensitive "name=ID" 
        }
        ...
    }
```