# Implementing case insensitive In Xtext editor

Tags: java, eclipse, dsl, xtext

[When i search for solution online i found this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889847/match-string-in-xtext-regardless-of-upper-lower-case)

In above code i thought it will help me to achieve my solution but i dont know how to add the above code in my current mwe2 workflow. i tried what he mentioned but i am getting exception so i thought i was making mistake due to lack xtext knowledge

just for more understanding see my mwe2 workflow

```
    language = StandardLanguage {
        name = "com.herzog.pmide.RoutingLineINI"
        fileExtensions = "ini"
        referencedResource = "platform:/resource/com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext.model/model/pmrouting.genmodel"
        fragment = ecore2xtext.Ecore2XtextValueConverterServiceFragment2 auto-inject {}

        fragment = org.eclipse.xtext.generator.adapter.FragmentAdapter {
            fragment = org.eclipse.xtext.generator.ecore2xtext.FormatterFragment {}
        }

        serializer = {
            generateStub = false
        }
        validator = {
        // composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator"
        }

        formatter = {
            generateStub = true
        }

        scopeProvider = {
            ignoreCase = true
        }
        parserGenerator = {
            options = {
                ignoreCase = true
            }
        }
    }
```

By doing above i am getting exception as below

```
0    [main] INFO  text.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator  - Initializing Xtext generator
8    [main] INFO  lipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup  - Adding generated EPackage 'org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.TypesPackage'
476  [main] WARN  lipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup  - Skipping conflicting project ini4j at 'archive:file:/C:/Users/HUSER02/git/pm-ide_local4/com.herzog.pmide.tools.importutility/libs/ini4j-0.5.4.jar!/' and using 'archive:file:/C:/Users/HUSER02/git/pm-ide_local4/com.herzog.pmide.nl/libs/ini4j-0.5.4.jar!/' instead.
707  [main] INFO  lipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup  - Registering project com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext at 'file:/C:/Users/HUSER02/git/pm-ide_local4/com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext/'
708  [main] INFO  lipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup  - Registering project com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext.tests at 'file:/C:/Users/HUSER02/git/pm-ide_local4/com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext.tests/'
708  [main] INFO  lipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup  - Registering project com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext.ide at 'file:/C:/Users/HUSER02/git/pm-ide_local4/com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext.ide/'
709  [main] INFO  lipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup  - Registering project com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext.ui at 'file:/C:/Users/HUSER02/git/pm-ide_local4/com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext.ui/'
709  [main] INFO  lipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup  - Registering project com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext.ui.tests at 'file:/C:/Users/HUSER02/git/pm-ide_local4/com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext.ui.tests/'
722  [main] INFO  lipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup  - Using resourceSet registry. The registered Packages will not be registered in the global EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE!
941  [main] INFO  clipse.emf.mwe.utils.GenModelHelper  - Registered GenModel 'http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/Xbase/XAnnotations' from 'platform:/resource/org.eclipse.xtext.xbase/model/Xbase.genmodel'
944  [main] INFO  clipse.emf.mwe.utils.GenModelHelper  - Registered GenModel 'http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/xbase/Xtype' from 'platform:/resource/org.eclipse.xtext.xbase/model/Xbase.genmodel'
955  [main] INFO  clipse.emf.mwe.utils.GenModelHelper  - Registered GenModel 'http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/xbase/Xbase' from 'platform:/resource/org.eclipse.xtext.xbase/model/Xbase.genmodel'
955  [main] INFO  clipse.emf.mwe.utils.GenModelHelper  - Registered GenModel 'http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/common/JavaVMTypes' from 'platform:/resource/org.eclipse.xtext.common.types/model/JavaVMTypes.genmodel'
967  [main] INFO  clipse.emf.mwe.utils.GenModelHelper  - Registered GenModel 'http://pmrouting/1.0' from 'platform:/resource/com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext.model/model/pmrouting.genmodel'
1830 [main] INFO  text.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator  - Generating com.herzog.pmide.RoutingLineINI
error(101): ../com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext/src-gen/com/herzog/pmide/parser/antlr/lexer/InternalRoutingLineINILexer.g:244:1: rule A_1 redefinition
error(101): ../com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext/src-gen/com/herzog/pmide/parser/antlr/lexer/InternalRoutingLineINILexer.g:246:1: rule B_1 redefinition
error(101): ../com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext/src-gen/com/herzog/pmide/parser/antlr/lexer/InternalRoutingLineINILexer.g:248:1: rule C_1 redefinition
error(101): ../com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext/src-gen/com/herzog/pmide/parser/antlr/lexer/InternalRoutingLineINILexer.g:250:1: rule D_1 redefinition
error(101): ../com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext/src-gen/com/herzog/pmide/parser/antlr/lexer/InternalRoutingLineINILexer.g:254:1: rule M_1 redefinition
error(101): ../com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext/src-gen/com/herzog/pmide/parser/antlr/lexer/InternalRoutingLineINILexer.g:256:1: rule P_1 redefinition
error(101): ../com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext/src-gen/com/herzog/pmide/parser/antlr/lexer/InternalRoutingLineINILexer.g:258:1: rule R_1 redefinition
error(101): ../com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext/src-gen/com/herzog/pmide/parser/antlr/lexer/InternalRoutingLineINILexer.g:260:1: rule S_1 redefinition
error(101): ../com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext/src-gen/com/herzog/pmide/parser/antlr/lexer/InternalRoutingLineINILexer.g:262:1: rule U_1 redefinition
error(101): ../com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext/src-gen/com/herzog/pmide/parser/antlr/lexer/InternalRoutingLineINILexer.g:264:1: rule W_1 redefinition
error(3):  cannot find tokens file ..\com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext\src-gen\com\herzog\pmide\parser\antlr\internal\InternalRoutingLineINILexer.tokens
12930 [main] INFO  text.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator  - Generating common infrastructure
12957 [main] ERROR mf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher  - Problems running workflow com.herzog.pmide.GenerateRoutingLineINI: 
[ERROR]: GeneratorException: (Element: -UNKNOWN-; Reported by: XtextGenerator)
     org.eclipse.xtext.util.RuntimeIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HUSER02\git\pm-ide_local4\com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext\..\com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext\src-gen\com\herzog\pmide\parser\antlr\lexer\InternalRoutingLineINILexer.tokens (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.JavaIoFileSystemAccess.readBinaryFile(JavaIoFileSystemAccess.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.AbstractFileSystemAccess2.readBinaryFile(AbstractFileSystemAccess2.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2$3.getAntlrTokenFile(AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.AntlrTokenDefProvider.getTokenDefMap(AntlrTokenDefProvider.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.cleanupParserTokensFile(AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.runAntlr(XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.generateProductionGrammar(XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.doGenerate(XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.generate(AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment2.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment2.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator.invokeInternal(XtextGenerator.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HUSER02\git\pm-ide_local4\com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext\..\com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext\src-gen\com\herzog\pmide\parser\antlr\lexer\InternalRoutingLineINILexer.tokens (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.JavaIoFileSystemAccess.readBinaryFile(JavaIoFileSystemAccess.java:239)
    ... 20 more

java.lang.RuntimeException: Problems running workflow com.herzog.pmide.GenerateRoutingLineINI: 
[ERROR]: GeneratorException: (Element: -UNKNOWN-; Reported by: XtextGenerator)
     org.eclipse.xtext.util.RuntimeIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HUSER02\git\pm-ide_local4\com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext\..\com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext\src-gen\com\herzog\pmide\parser\antlr\lexer\InternalRoutingLineINILexer.tokens (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.JavaIoFileSystemAccess.readBinaryFile(JavaIoFileSystemAccess.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.AbstractFileSystemAccess2.readBinaryFile(AbstractFileSystemAccess2.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2$3.getAntlrTokenFile(AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.AntlrTokenDefProvider.getTokenDefMap(AntlrTokenDefProvider.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.cleanupParserTokensFile(AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.runAntlr(XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.generateProductionGrammar(XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.doGenerate(XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.generate(AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment2.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment2.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator.invokeInternal(XtextGenerator.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HUSER02\git\pm-ide_local4\com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext\..\com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext\src-gen\com\herzog\pmide\parser\antlr\lexer\InternalRoutingLineINILexer.tokens (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.JavaIoFileSystemAccess.readBinaryFile(JavaIoFileSystemAccess.java:239)
    ... 20 more

    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
[ERROR]: GeneratorException: (Element: -UNKNOWN-; Reported by: XtextGenerator)
     org.eclipse.xtext.util.RuntimeIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HUSER02\git\pm-ide_local4\com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext\..\com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext\src-gen\com\herzog\pmide\parser\antlr\lexer\InternalRoutingLineINILexer.tokens (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.JavaIoFileSystemAccess.readBinaryFile(JavaIoFileSystemAccess.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.AbstractFileSystemAccess2.readBinaryFile(AbstractFileSystemAccess2.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2$3.getAntlrTokenFile(AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.AntlrTokenDefProvider.getTokenDefMap(AntlrTokenDefProvider.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.cleanupParserTokensFile(AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.runAntlr(XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.generateProductionGrammar(XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.doGenerate(XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.generate(AbstractAntlrGeneratorFragment2.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment2.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment2.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator.invokeInternal(XtextGenerator.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HUSER02\git\pm-ide_local4\com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext\..\com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext\src-gen\com\herzog\pmide\parser\antlr\lexer\InternalRoutingLineINILexer.tokens (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.JavaIoFileSystemAccess.readBinaryFile(JavaIoFileSystemAccess.java:239)
    ... 20 more

    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.handleIssues(Mwe2Bridge.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:102)
    ... 4 more
```

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: can you give the complete log

Comment: did you play around with timeouts?

Comment: i edited my workflow after doing that i am getting following exception....i will post complete log ..after lot of search and try i posted this question..

Comment: hmm without beeing able to reproduce no idea ....

Comment: did you have a look at the timeout thing?

Answer (score 0):

To use case insentive languages with the new workflow use

```
    language = StandardLanguage {
        name = "org.xtext.example.mydsl1.MyDsl"
        fileExtensions = "mydsl1"

        serializer = {
            generateStub = false
        }
        validator = {
            // composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator"
        }
        scopeProvider = {
            ignoreCase = true
        }
        parserGenerator = {
            options = {
                ignoreCase = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i done this still i am getting above same exception.

Comment: As I said I need a reproducible example grammar

Comment: Do u want my ".xtext" file ? which you can check on your side ?

Comment: For example if you log is really complete or increasing (antlr) timeouts helps. I have no idea if your grammar has 10 or 10000 lines

Comment: ok. can you tell me how i can increase my timeouts means syntax..@Christian Dietrich

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1086458&goto=1764305&#msg_1764305

Comment: i added complete log now of exception...... please check last time.. @christian Dietrich.. by increasing timeouts

Comment: Is it possible you have something strange in your grammar that could lead to this redefinition errors